# How to get the correct type shown with TypeOf()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

When using

```
const source = Observable.from([{name: 'Joe', age: 30}, {name: 'Frank', age: 20},{name: 'Ryan', age: 50}]);
console.log(typeof (source));
```

The Type is written as **Object()**.

Is there a way to have more precise information? I would like to know if it is an Observable().

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :-

```
source.constructor

source.constructor.prototype

source.constructor.toString().indexOf // for logical check 

instanceof //operator.
```

It's depend on what's your need.

Answer (score 4):

All class instances will have `typeof` of `"object"`, that's just how javascript works.

If you want to know whether or not `source` is an instance of `Observable` then use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
console.log(source instanceof Observable);
```